# IIS hosted web core and websockets

Tags: asp.net, websocket, asp.net-4.5, iis-8

I have a web app that uses new WebSocket feature of ASP.NET 4.5. I have a custom handler that does following:

```csh
public class WebsocketHandler : IHttpHandler
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        if (context.IsWebSocketRequest)
        {
            context.AcceptWebSocketRequest(WebSocketRequest);
        }
    }

    public bool IsReusable { get { return false; } }

    private async Task WebSocketRequest(AspNetWebSocketContext context)
    {
         //Processing
    }
}
```

This works well when I host my app on IIS 8, but when I run this app in a IIS hosted web core, `IsWebSocketRequest` property is always `fasle`.

So, the questin is: does IIS 8 hosted web core supports websockets and if it does, what I need to do to enable it?

Comment: Do you run the hosted web core on Windows Server 2012/Windows 8 or on a previous Windows version?

Comment: I run it on Windows Server 2012 with enabled Websockets feature. Maybe I need some special setting in my applicationHost.config file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I've figured out that HWC **does support** WebSockets by the fact that IIS Express 8 does, and it is basically a wrapper over HWC. After that I've examined IIS Express `applicationhost.config` and found that there were a few things there that I've missed.

The complete list of the changes that I've made to my HWC `applicationhost.config` to enable Websockets support is following:

- Add `<section name="webSocket" overrideModeDefault="Deny" />` element to the `<sectionGroup name="system.webServer">` of `<configSections>`
- Add `<webSocket />` element to `<system.webServer>`
- Add `<add name="WebSocketModule" image="%windir%\System32\inetsrv\iiswsock.dll" />` element to `<globalModules>`
- Add `<add name="WebSocketModule" lockItem="true" />` element  to the `<modules>`

After that Websockets worked like a charm.